# Bind data from controller to View -> Control

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller, data-binding, user-controls

I am implementing MVC in a WinForms Application. In the view there is a combobox control. I have declare a property called SheetLoader with getter and setter:

```
public BindingSource SheetLoader
{
    get { return (BindingSource)comboBox_workSheetList.DataSource; }
    set { this.comboBox_workSheetList.DataSource = (BindingSource)value; }
}
```

In controller I want to access setter above and bind the `BindingSource` to the combobox.

```
view.SheetLoader = _bindingSource;
```

But this way is not working. The combobox will not assign any item.
I have debugged it, However the `value` gets data.

Please help me to bind data from controller to View -> Control.

Comment: How does the controller refer to the view? Through an interface? If so, does the interface define `SheetLoader`? As a side note, why would the controller directly access properties of the view? Maybe I misunderstood MVC, but isn't the controller supposed to hand over a model to the view?

Comment: sorry. Updated the question. the Items are not display on Combo-box.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of your combobox.